# How to extract all matches from a text on a Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have  tuple like this: `{title: chararray, textWithLinks: chararray}`

Example: `(Title1, some text [[link]] some text [[link]] some text... )`

I need to extract all links from a text and get tuple:
`(Title,(link1, link2, link3...))`

How do I can do this? RegexExtract or RegexExtractAll extract only one or few links, but not all.

Comment: please share sample data

Comment: Provide a sample of the test data and the output required. Also mention what you have tried and where you are being struck.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom UDF that will extract links and return a DataBag with them.
As UDF is any custom java code that extends EvalFunc you can do whatever you want to extract these links